# how to make a regular expression for this?

Tags: regex, regular-language

I want to make a regular expression on the string "{{c1::tiger}} is 
 a kind of {{c2::animal::something movable}}" to get the word "tiger" and "animal",and I have made this expression `\{\{c\d+::((?P<value>.*?)(:{0,2})(.*?))\}\}`,also I want to use `group('value')` to achieve this.The result word "tiger" is exactly what I need,but always get the wrong result "animal::something movable"(which I mean "animal"),could anyone help me to solve this problem?Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern that you tried contains 4 capturing groups and for the current example data group 1 and group 3 are empty.

To get `tiger` you could use a single capturing group with a negated character class:

```
\{\{c\d+::(?P<value>.*?)(?:::|}})
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/edN3jB/1)

If the closing `}}` have to be present, you could use:

```
\{\{c\d+::(?P<value>.*?)(?:::.*)?}}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uQpT4a/1)

Comment: how about the word "animal"?I use this pattern but get the wrong word "animal::something movable".

Comment: @bmxbmx3 The current pattern gets tiger and animal in the `value` group. Do you mean like this? `\{\{c\d+::(?P<value>\S+)}}` https://regex101.com/r/cFNvU9/1

Comment: sorry I didn't notice that you had modified the answer,your answer is what I need.But could you tell me why my regular expression `\{\{c\d+::((?P<value>.*?)(:{0,2})(.*?))\}\}` is wrong?Thanks.

Comment: This part in your pattern `((?P<value>.*?)(:{0,2})` uses a quantifier `.*?` and `{0,2}` which mean 0+ times and 0 - 2 times so 0 times will also be ok. Then the last group `(.*?)` will match 0+ times non greedy until it can match the last `}}`

Comment: and what does the pattern `(?:::|}})` mean in your regex demo?Especially why to use `?:::`?

Comment: The `(?:` means a non capturing group using a pipe which will mean either `::` or `}}`.

Answer (score 0):

This would work for your example String:

```
c1::(?P<valueTiger>[a-z]*).*?c2::(?P<valueAnimal>[a-z]*)
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/7DDcGC/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
\{\{c\d+::(?P<value>[^:}]+)(?::{0,2}([^}]+))?\}\}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lJTRSX/2)